# Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a $C^1$ map. Then the restriction of $f$ to any open set is not surjective

Tags: analysis, inverse-function-theorem

I try to use inverse map theorem in a function defined interns of $f$ or implicit map theorem but I can't get this result.

Comment: In case it helps, this is a consequence of [Sard's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem).